# How to pass values of drop down from html template to views in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I need to send the value of the selected option in a drop down to the views.

**Html** code of template is as follows:

```
<select name="version" id="version" onchange="location = this.value;">
    <option>Select version to compare with</option>
    {%for ver in version_list%}
        <option value={{ver}} href="{% url 'process_data' ver %}">{{ver}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Above html code is giving me the following error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/11.5.1.18900-96

http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/11.5.1.18900-97


Using the URLconf defined in Piechart_Excel.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
index/
process_data/<str:ver> [name='process_data']

The current path, index/11.5.1.18900-96, didn't match any of these.
```

However, if I am sending the value as follows i.e. without any drop down:

```
<a href="{% url 'process_data' ver1 %}">{{ver}}</a>
```

everything is working as expected.

**Urls.py** file content is as follows:

```
from django.urls import path
from fusioncharts import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', views.index, name='index'),
    path('process_data/<str:ver>', views.process_data, name='process_data'),
]
```

Can anyone tell why is it not working in the case of drop down but working otherwise? If we have to send any value from the html template using drop down, then how to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using a link inside an option tag, which I argue there are better ways however ... you can try this.

```
<select name="version" id="version" onchange="location = this.value;">
      <option>Select version to compare with</option>
      {%for ver in version_list%}
      **<option value="{% url 'process_data' ver %}">{{ver}}</option>**
      {% endfor %}
  </select>
```

You also might have to edit the onchange event

```
onChange="window.location.href=this.value"
```

If that doesn't work then you could convert to links and then convert it into a dropdown menu using css or a css framework.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="{% url 'process_data' ver %}">{{ver}}</a></li>
<ul>
```

Complete Dropdown example

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Select version to compare with
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    {%for ver in version_list%}
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'process_data' ver %}">{{ver}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

This is assuming you import bootstrap see the following links for details:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

Comment: My requirement is to have links in the dropdown, clicking on which would take me to a different page. Hence I had added the links. 
So you suggest to use lists and convert that to dropdown ?

Comment: Yes, Select / Options is usually reserved for use in forms. I'll add a more complete example.

Comment: Ok, can you please share that example?

Comment: In the mean time, I tried wit the following: 

    <select name="version" id="version" onchange="window.location.href=this.value;">
 <option>Select version to compare with</option>
 {%for ver1 in final_version_list%}
  {% if version != ver1|split:":" %}
   <tr><td><option value="{% url 'process_data' ver %}">{{ver1}}</option></td></tr>
  {% endif%}
 {% endfor %}

But now getting the error: 

Reverse for 'process_data' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['process_data\\/(?P<ver>[^/]+)$']

Comment: I just tested it and this works <select name="version" id="version" onchange="location = this.value;">
        <option>Select version to compare with</option>
        {%for ver in version_list%}
        **<option value="{% url 'process_data' ver %}">{{ver}}</option>**
        {% endfor %}
    </select>

Comment: Hi Teaque, Thanks a lot for the inputs and it worked. So can you please say originally what mistake I had made?

Comment: The href attribute in a select option tag is invalid. Instead by passing the link in the option value attribute then it passes that value which is Django url (/process_data/11.5.1.18900-97) minus the host(http://127.0.0.1:8000) to the select onchange which then sets the location to that value and changing the location causes the page to render and that request is then piped to your Django url settings. Before you were only passing 11.5.1.18900-97 to the onchange attribute and it appended to the current page index. window.location.href would be necessary if you were wanting to external link.